# How to use text-overflow:ellipsis with unknown width

Tags: ellipsis, css

I have this `label` which might be any width and should use the CSS `text-overflow:ellipsis` property. I can't seem to be able to get it to work. `#a` works because the `width` is set and that's the expected result. How to get `#b` to work?

```
<div id="a">
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>checkbox label</label>
</div>

<div id="b">
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>checkbox label</label>
</div>

#a       {width:100px; background:#ddd;}
#a label {text-overflow:ellipsis; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; float:right; width:50px;}
#a a     {float:right}

#b       {width:100px; background:#ddd;}
#b label {text-overflow:ellipsis; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; float:right;}
#b a     {float:right}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6wusc/1/)

Comment: If it doesn't have a set width it will expand to contain the text, so there won't be any overflow. Possibly try set `max-width` instead of `width`?

Comment: the containing div has a set width. Is there no way to have all the elements on a single line?